# Using Fast Fourier Transform on matlab?

Tags: matlab, fft

I am having some difficulty in solving a simple 2D Poisson equation in Matlab using spectral methods in one direction on finite difference in the other.

I am obtaining a scaled version of the correct answer but can't work out why although I think it has something to do with the wavenumber.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the code can be seen below.

```
N = 32;
x = ((0:N-1)/N)*2*pi;
y = ((0:N-1)/N)*2*pi;
dx = 2*pi/N;
k  =  fftshift(-N/2:N/2-1);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f = (-2)*cos(X).*sin(Y);
f_comparison = cos(X).*sin(Y);
checker = 10;
u = zeros(N,N);
u_new = zeros(N,N);
f_hat = fftn(f);
while checker > 1*10^(-7);
    u_new_hat = fftn(u_new);
    for aa = 1:N
        for a = 1:N
            q1 = a+1;
            q2 = a-1;
            if q2 == 0
                q2 = N;
            end
            if q1 == N+1
                q1 = 1;
            end
            denom = ((dx^2)*((k(aa))^2))+2;
            u_new_hat(a,aa) = (1/denom)*((u_new_hat(q1,aa))+(u_new_hat(q2,aa))-((f_hat(a,aa))*(dx^2)));
        end
    end
    u_new = real(ifftn(u_new_hat));
    for aa = 1:N
        for a = 1:N
            u_checker(a,aa) = abs(u_new(a,aa)-u(a,aa));
        end
    end
    compare = max(u_checker);
    checker = max(compare);
    for aa = 1:N
        for a = 1:N
            u(a,aa) = u_new(a,aa);
        end
    end
end
%calculate scaling discrepency
ddd = f_comparison./u;
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Can you make a simpler "toy" problem that illustrates the issue?

Comment: I just need help with why the final result is scaled incorrectly. writing everything down with pen and paper what the code does should work but i am getting a poorly scaled result

Comment: A lot of us don't know what a Poisson equation is and how to solve it.  It's suggested that you narrow down your question into what exactly it is you're having trouble with, and phrase it in a way where more MATLAB answerers have the ability to answer your question.  I haven't written an answer yet because for one, you have a lot of code, and two I don't know where it is in your code that is causing you problems.